# Spinner android same item selection for just one particular item

Tags: android, android-layout, android-spinner

I am trying to implement a spinner in android.I want to fire an event for same selection for only one particular item in the spinner.Rest of the items behave as they do for regular spinner.
Any help would be really appreciated.Thanks.

```
setSelection(int position)
{
   boolean sameSelected = position == getSelectedItemPosition();
   super.setSelection(position);
   if (sameSelected) {
             getOnItemSelectedListener().onItemSelected(this,getSelectedView(),position,getSelectedItemId());
}
}
```

This code gives NuLLpointer exception in the getOnitemSelectedListener line inside the 'if' statement

Comment: post some of your code

Answer (score 0):

Use extended Spinner, it will invalidate the old selection and the event will fire again -

```
public class SpinnerTrigger extends Spinner {

public SpinnerTrigger(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public void setSelection(int position, boolean animate) {
    ignoreOldSelectionByReflection();
    super.setSelection(position, animate);
}

private void ignoreOldSelectionByReflection() {
    try {
        Class<?> c = this.getClass().getSuperclass().getSuperclass().getSuperclass();
        Field reqField = c.getDeclaredField("mOldSelectedPosition");
        reqField.setAccessible(true);
        reqField.setInt(this, -1);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("Exception Private", "ex", e);
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
}

@Override
public void setSelection(int position) {
    ignoreOldSelectionByReflection();
    super.setSelection(position);
}

}
```

Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

When you clicks again the currently selected item, then it can not fire any event. So you can not catch setOnItemSelectedListener for spinner to respond.

Answer (score 0):

the reason for null pointer was getselectedview() was returning null because it was setting the item for the first time and nothing was selected. Also for the particular item same selection i added another condition to the if statement as position == 3.Now its working fine.Thanks.